# How to deny access to network (Internet) for users group in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, internet, group-policy

I have Windows 7 prof installed without any AD. Just notebook for example. And I need to create Users group with limitations to access Internet via my application. Some accounts needs to have access but some - not. What services I need to use to make it possible?

May be some 3rd party freeware applications with API?

Comment: have you tried gpedit.msc in run command which allows admin to set the restrictions to usergroup & users?

Comment: I cant find where I can to add user or usergroup based policy to deny access. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

well its step by step process using gpedit.msc

1.open run command type `"gpedit.msc"` gp is nothing but group policy

2.click on `user configuration`

3.go to

```
Administrative templates -->network-->network connections
```

4.there you can set the options whatever you want regarding internet

atlast you can use this gpedit for various activities related to user restrictions like blocking run command,etc